# How to export a private key / public key into bytes with Python cryptography module?

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, python-cryptography

I tried many combinations of parameters of [`rsa.RSAPrivateKey.private_bytes`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPrivateKey.private_bytes) but none of them work:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import Encoding, PrivateFormat, PublicFormat, NoEncryption

private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(public_exponent=65537, key_size=2048, backend=default_backend())
pvt_bytes = private_key.private_bytes(Encoding.Raw, PrivateFormat.Raw, NoEncryption())
# ERROR
# ValueError: format is invalid with this key

public_key = private_key.public_key()
pub_bytes = public_key.public_bytes(Encoding.Raw, PublicFormat.Raw)

print(pvt_bytes, pub_bytes)
```

**Question: how to export/import a private key / public key into a bytes form with the Python `cryptography` module?**

The goal is to have a base64 encoded version of both like:

`uFWnMdqUALp2NcvKRxE8Fw2uWDbBjnSk5wveuL3DOp7Ct4AyYKpvccMEE63ooYoj4nblafAwXikakGPbCM4amg==`

Comment: RSA keys consist of various parameters, e.g. modulus, public and private exponent, and others. These can be output in different formats and encodings. Your question is missing information about which format and encoding you need. The example you posted is too short to represent a complete key, at most one of the parameters.

Comment: @Topaco for pub key, I found that public_key.public_bytes(Encoding.OpenSSH, PublicFormat.OpenSSH) works: `ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC+O7m47/g26gtOrTBGi2Ly2gP7fL3IhjKjhF1+3lvgv/ZLj5ds77pzdFEGJuC8bhGKxaTUHRLYLzlLUWfQd0NLrUxlLW6QVpT0OS5npSqkGjRQ2I0F3YYkqBBFrdXTFQv3RTUz/VU6X6SiYBRDgZ43rtYQ17fNbB+/cpbPMsiXKHUjlCzOYZ6Yi9ntAXEKY2Xkb1FGXtu0s8PBWUJoQ603a2TBdceyF14t8J5QPycIDvEXAFv/h9zWM8F2UY/D4K8kGcgXzd3dXNln6ICiCTGtF8vCilP4TOh5oHtJgo0B1ckO9NYIocRFD5Un+XvXTpH+nNeCZopYmdETlO/q2SIV`

Comment: @Topaco, is there a similar format for private key, as a one-line key, without all the `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` delimiters? I'm looking for something similar to `ssh-rsa <long-string>` in one line, to encode a private key with `cryptography` module. Any idea?

Comment: If the format does not matter, use PKCS8 for the private key, SubjectPublicKeyInfo for the public key, DER as encoding and Base64 decode the data. But note that the format should be appropriate for the application, otherwise you may have to do conversions.

Comment: @Topaco what is the most common format for both nowadays? `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...` for the pvt, and `ssh-rsa ...` for the pub? is that correct?

Comment: No, this is not correct. For the private key PKCS#8 is often used as format, for the public key X.509/SPKI.

Comment: Ok so for private key PCKS8 `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBVgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAUAwggE8AgEAAkEAq7BFUpkGp3+LQmlQ
Yx2eqzDV+xeG8kx/sQFV1...`, and for the pubkey, something like:
`(public-key (rsa-pkcs1-md5 (e #03#)  (n   |ANHCG85jXFG...`,  is that correct @Topaco?

Comment: X.509/SPKI has PEM encoded the header `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and is specified in pyca/cryptography with `PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo`. Have a look at the [pyca/cryptography docs](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.PublicFormat).

Comment: If you don't need the headers, use the [DER encoding](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#der) (instead of the PEM encoding) and Base64 encode the data.